# How to open a file by its path relative to the Python module, when that module is tested with py.test?

Tags: python, pytest

I have a module inside a package which figures out the path of the invoking python program:

```
pathname = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

from where it will pick up a `mydata.json` to read some parameter values.

This works fine when executing the script using `python xyz.py`

But the same stuff, when done using `py.test` at the directory, the path just points to some binary: `/home/user/venv/bin/data/data.json`

Basically the calling script is assumed to be `py.test` itself, which is located in the `venv/bin`.

How to overcome this problem ? I want to fetch the path of the script which in turn is being processed by `py.test` itself (via the module).

Answer (score 7):

If i understand the problem correctly you should be using

```
import json
import os

path_to_current_file = os.path.realpath(__file__)
current_directory = os.path.split(path_to_current_file)[0]
path_to_file = os.path.join(current_directory, "mydata.json")
with open(path_to_file) as mydata:
    my_json_data = json.load(mydata)
```

Answer (score 3):

Slightly different version from the one offered above:

```
path_to_current_file = os.path.realpath(__file__)
current_directory = os.path.dirname(path_to_current_file)
path_to_file = os.path.join(current_directory, "mydata.json")
```